# When proving inequalities with induction, do you need to show how you got to the next step, or just show that it holds?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Sorry for the confusing title but I find this hard to formulate. Let me show with an example, I am supposed to prove that:
$\frac{1}{1^2} + \frac{1}{2^2} + \frac{1}{3^2} +...+\frac{1}{n^2} \leq 2- \frac{1}{n},  \forall n\geq1$

So omitting the base case and hypothesis I come to the induction step which is:

$... + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq 2 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}$

And from my understanding of induction I have to rewrite the right hand side, to be something less than or equal to this expression:

$2-\frac{1}{k+1}$

What confuses me, do I need to show step by step how I come from the second expression to the third, or simply show that this inequality is true:

$2 - \frac{1}{k} + \frac{1}{(k+1)^2} \leq 2-\frac{1}{k+1} $

Like, will showing that the expression above is true, be sufficient formulation of the proof by induction?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Math SE. I've made a minor change to your text. In answer to your question, yes, that would complete the proof of the inductive step.

Comment: Yes, this is enough, the induction step $k \mapsto k+1$ is in fact showing that the claim, which by hypothesis you postulate holds for a fixed but arbitrary $k$, holds for $k+1$. So, it consists precisely of proving your last inequality.